# Disorders in tight binding model and periodicity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, tight-binding

Does introducing disorders in tight binding models disrupt the periodicity of the lattice? If it does, doesn't this contradict with the assumptions and purposes of the tight binding model as a periodic potential? Can we still use such a model when periodicity and translation symmetry are broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, spatial disorder in the tight binding model breaks translation symmetry. The tight-binding is certainly motivated by a periodic potential, but once the formalism is in place we are free to add perturbations and see what happens. Whether this is a good model for some underlying (non-lattice) disorder is another question. In other words, once we have a second-quantized Hamiltonian

$$H = -t\sum_{\langle ij\rangle\sigma} (c_{i,\sigma}^\dagger c_{j,\sigma} + \text{h.c.})$$

where the $c^\dagger_{i,\sigma}$ create position-space orbital states, it is certainly natural to consider all Hamiltonians of this form (i.e. adding all Hermitian operators built out of the $c_i^\dagger, c_j$, such as $\sum V_i c_i^\dagger c_i$ to study Anderson localization). Many models (Hubbard model, t-J model, Anderson insulator, many-body localized states) with interesting physics result.

You may be wondering about the [usual derivation of the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) using hopping integrals and explicit wavefunctions. That is, of course, dependent on exact translation symmetry, or else we cannot talk about momentum or Bloch states. Solving the spectrum of a general position-space model is not simple.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.